# Banner ads not showing in Android emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, emulation, ads

I have this code for testing bannerads in the Android emulator. I have the proper imports in place. Calling `this.showBannerAd()` stops the emulator from launching the app. Any inputs on the same would help.

Constructor code:

```
constructor(  platform: Platform, 
              private admobFree: AdMobFree,              

            ) {
                if (!platform.is('core')) {
                  this.showBannerAd();
              }
            }
 async showBannerAd(){
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true
    }
     this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

    try {
      const result = this.admobFree.banner.prepare();
      console.log("Admob result: ", result)

    }

    catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't know the answer (and probably won't even with more information) but it would certainly be helpful for answerers if you could add what version of android your emulator is using. Also, does it only happen on the emulator, or on your hardware phone as well?

Answer (score 2):

> it's important to enable test ads during development because Google
>   does not allow developers to use real banners while an app is in
>   development.

There are 2 ways to implement this:

Use the **Banner Id**           `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`
Or use **Interstitial**         `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`

Re-run your app. If the ad is a Google ad, you'll see a Test Ad label centered at the top of the ad (banner, interstitial, or rewarded video).